# I got rid of unity but have gnome-panel: blank screen

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome-panel, openbox

I got rid of unity in my Ubuntu 11.10 on a dell mini following the steps as in [this](http://linux-software-news-tutorials.blogspot.com/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-oneiric-remove-unity-and.html) post.  I had ensured that I installed `gnome-panel` before I did this and removed unity from within `gnome-panel`.

When I rebooted, all I have now is the blank scree with some text where my computer is running tests:

It is stuck now at `* Checking battery status... [OK ]`

Did I do something horribly wrong? As this is a netbook, I don't have a dvd tray to try and rescue ubuntu.

If this is something horribly wrong, what do you suggest I do? I have access to usb ports and can try a fresh install of say openbox or something via usb if that is possible.

### Edit:

I don't have network access from the grun/root option. So I can't update my nvidia driver as in [here](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-install-nvidia-graphics-driver-in-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat)

Answer (score 0):

First, the package you should install to get the "classic" Gnome desktop is `gnome-session-fallback`.

I guess you just removed LightDM and didn't installed GDM, or GDM is not being run at startup.

To solve this, when you get to that part it seems the system is stuck (showing `Checking battery state`) press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. This should take you to a prompt where you can login. After logging in, install the missing packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

After all is installed, just execute in the same terminal

```
sudo service gdm start
```

This should show you the normal login window.

#### Edit

I'm assuming that despite your not being able to connect to your network now you have some connection configured in the system. To see the list of available networks, use

```
nmcli con list
```

This will display the list of the networks in your system, giving a name and uuid. If for example, your connection is named MYCONNECTION you can connect to it using

```
nmcli con up id MYCONNECTION
```

Then you should have network conectivity and can download/install the required packages.

Comment: Did all that but since I don't have network connectivity I can't `apt-get` sh*t `:P` (please read my edit from about 1 hour before your answr)

Comment: You really dont have network or you just can't connect to your network using your computer?

Comment: I cant connect to my network using my computer from GRUB/root.

Comment: Sorry man... I took the easy way out. I reinstalled but Ubuntu 10.04.